# regex replace certain character but not for particular set in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var str='select * from where item1=abcd and price>=20';
```

I am using the below code to replace the '=' to empty space

```
str=str.replace(/[=]/g, " ")
```

but it is also replacing  `'>='` . I want >= not to be replaced with any thing and also for some others condition like `'==' or '<='` etc.

So my output should be - `'select * from where item abcd and price>=20'`

Please help me to achieve this.

Comment: [`.replace(/(\w+)\s*=\s*(\w+)/g, '$1 $2')`](https://regex101.com/r/gkwEfR/1)

Comment: thanks, this is working. but i am not able to understand this. Can you please  describe more about this or you can point to some tutorial? I will accept this as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below regex for replacement

```
/([a-z0-9]+)\s*=\s*([a-z0-9]+)/gi
```

and replace it with `$1 $2`.

1. `([a-z0-9]+)`: Match one or more alphanumeric characters and add them to capturing group
2. `\s*`: Zero or more space characters
3. `=`: Equal sign
4. `gi`: `g`: Global flag to match all possible matches. `i`: Case-insensitive flag.

`$n` in the replacement part is the *nth* captured group value.

```js
var regex = /([a-z0-9]+)\s*=\s*([a-z0-9]+)/gi;
var str = 'select * from where item1=abcd and price>=20';

console.log(str.replace(regex, '$1 $2'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace an equal sign with a letter or number on either side with the corresponding characters around a space.

```
str.replace(/([a-zA-Z0-9])=([a-zA-Z0-9])/, '$1 $2')
```

In regex [] means "the set of", so [a-zA-Z0-9] is one character from the set of any lowercase, uppercase, or digit.

Answer (score 0):

Simple and dirty trick. Remove `g` from `regx`

```js
var str='select * from where item1=abcd and price>=20';
console.log(str.replace(/[=]/, " "))
```

Comment: Won't work if there are multiple conditions or the `<=`, `>=` or `==` condition appears before `=`.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to approach these problems is to *capture* everything you wish to skip, and then *not capture* everything you wish you remove. In your case:

```
(>=|<=|==|'[^']*(?:''[^']*)*')|=
```

and replace with `$1`.

Working example: https://regex101.com/r/3pT9ib/3

- First we have a capturing group: `(`...`)`, which is captured into `$1`.

  - The group matched `>=` and `<=`. I also threw in `==` (is this valid in SQL?) and escaped SQL strings, just for the example.
- If we were not able to match the group, we can safely match and remove the leftover `=`.

This approach is explained nicely here: [Regex Pattern to Match, Excluding when... / Except between](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23589174/7586)